# Go API for Tibco EMS

Tags: go, tibco-ems

Anyone aware of there any Go API for Tibco EMS? I've been searching, but came up empty handed. Some people seem to be using C API via Cgo, but that's not what I'm after. I'd prefer pure Go API at this point.

P.S. Not sure SO is appropriate for this question, but cannot seem to ask on Stack Exchange.

Comment: What is your ems version?

Comment: I got two separate versions 6.3 and 8.2

Comment: I think you should be able to find the supported api's under EMS installation/samples

Comment: There's nothing Go related there.

Comment: Disappointing response from TIBCO: 

Thank you for contacting TIBCO Support.EMS client libraries are provided in C, Java, .NET and COBOL languages. We do not have any client libraries or sample code for EMS for GO programming language.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK is JMS a standard describing the application interface (API) for using a messaging system. EMS is one flavour implemented by TIBCO. The standard leaves room in some details of implementation of the interface and does not describe the protocol used on the wire (tcp). To cut it short, for a pure Go client the internal EMS protocol would be needed to make the raw tcp stuff in Go and make the mapping to the JMS/EMS API. As EMS ships with C header only files (the pure API) and shared object files I guess that this mapping is completely TIBCO internal know how - and cannot be taken up by anyone else than TIBCO. I myself tried with Cgo, but that hinders to make the interesting stuff, like (for example) compile for ARM and do some IoT use cases :)

Answer (score 0):

Download Tibco EMS, this contains c_dotnet_client.tar.gz and c_dev_kit.tar.gz. These packages contain the include header files and libtibems.so which you can use from cgo.

Refer to this ems client for Go: https://github.com/mmussett/ems. Add the following flags to your copy of the ems client to link to the header files and the shared library:

```
#cgo CFLAGS: -I./lib/ems/include
#cgo LDFLAGS: -L${SRCDIR}/lib/ems -ltibems -Wl,-rpath=${SRCDIR}/lib/ems
```